# How to restrict URL based on Apache settings?

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, server

how can we restrict URL of another application based on the login of another application?

for example:

there are 2 application application A and application B.

if user is logged in in application A. then entering application B url is accessible otherwise redirect to application A.

Comment: What do you mean with "restrict URL based on Apache settings"? A simple form to share  authorization information between two apps is a shared (http only) cookie. Maybe even basic auth [RFC 1945](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945) is enough. A more advanced / secure approach is shown in [How to Implement Single Sign On](https://auth0.com/learn/how-to-implement-single-sign-on/)

Comment: As @andih says, looks like ou want to use application A to authenticate user in A and B. Is better config this on your application but you can do this with apache http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2003/09/11/kerberos.html?page=2